# Controllers managed by the dependency injection container and "action" suffix

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony 2+, when you describe the method that is executed for a specific route, you can use either:

```
MyBundle:MyController:hello
```

Or, given that you [setup `MyController` to be managed by the dependency injection container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) as service `my_controller`:

```
my_controller:helloAction
```

Why does Symfony expect the `Action` suffix in one case but not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the second variant **NEED** helloAction instead of hello,
>   like in the first variant?

**Nope!**
Don't be misled.

When defining [controller as service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html), the controller method names can be whatever name you want.
Thus, if in your controller you have method called `hello`, so you must define it in the routing config as `hello` only, instead `helloAction` (which is wrong). That is why symfony **expects** for a valid callable name.

On the other hand, when extending from default framework controller, Symfony expects all methods name have a `Action`  suffix (That's just a convention rather than technical requirement, see `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface#ControllerNameParser`, [line 78](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Controller/ControllerNameParser.php#L78)).

Here is a practical exemple:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

/** My controller as service */
class DefaultController 
{
    public function hello() 
    {
        return new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response('Hello!');
    }
}
```

My route settings:

```
# app/config/touting.yml
hello:
    path: /hello
    # NOTE: Method name is hello, not helloAction
    defaults: {_controller: app.controller.default:hello}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to reply @felipsmartins. I think I may not have been clear before though. My question is: why does Symfony expect the controllers registered as services to not use the `Action` suffix but expects non-service controllers to use that suffix? I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Actually, the question has nothing to do with extending from the base controller class.  It is the framework ControllerResolver which appends 'Action' to controller method names just like it assumes the controller class lives under Bundle\Controller.  Down voted accordingly.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for taking the time to downvoting. When I said "**when extending from default framework controller**" I mean "when using the Symfony default workflow", and not basecontroller adds/requires any suffix.

Comment: @conradk That's just a convention. I've edited (a bit) the answer.